# SQL UPDATE SET interchanges values

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, set

I update a View to get in two columns the same value, but it interchanges the two values instead of just setting it. My (reduced for so) view `UpdateADAuftrag2` is this.

```
SELECT     dbo.CSDokument.AD1, dbo.UpdateAS400zuSellingBenutzer2.BenutzerNr
FROM       dbo.AS400Auftrag 
           INNER JOIN
           dbo.CSDokument ON dbo.AS400Auftrag.Angebotsnummer = dbo.CSDokument.Angebotsnummer 
           INNER JOIN
           dbo.UpdateAS400zuSellingBenutzer2 ON dbo.AS400Auftrag.AD = dbo.UpdateAS400zuSellingBenutzer2.SchluesselWert 
           AND 
           dbo.CSDokument.AD1 <> dbo.UpdateAS400zuSellingBenutzer2.BenutzerNr
           WHERE     (dbo.AS400Auftrag.AD IS NOT NULL)
```

The important part is `dbo.CSDokument.AD1 <> dbo.UpdateAS400zuSellingBenutzer2.BenutzerNr`

`AD1` is user number for external workers and `BenutzerNr` means user number. So e.g. the person Charlie Brown is an external worker and has the user number 31. When in `AD1` is 31 - Charlie Brown is the external worker for this document (order in this case).

The Update statement loos like this

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[UpdateADAuftrag2]
 SET [AD1] = [BenutzerNr]
```

I have for example these values

```
AD1 | BenutzerNr
31  | 54
99  | 384
112 | 93
```

after the update the result is this

```
AD1 | BenutzerNr
54  | 31
384 | 99
93  | 112
```

Why not this?

```
AD1 | BenutzerNr
54  | 54
384 | 384
93  | 93
```

edit: `UpdateAS400zuSellingBenutzer` is also a View, but as far as I can see it includes only `BenutzerNr` and not `AD1`.

Comment: I think I've found the bug. I'll write an answer as soon as I've completed a solution. Short answer: There were 2 bugs - Bug 1 View UpdateAS400zuSellingBenutzer2 had 2 results sometimes for one entry in CSDokument and Bug 2 There were 2 entries in Table AS400Auftrag and then it switched between these two entries. So it just looked like the `SET` switched the two entries but it was just by chance. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 bugs - Bug 1 View UpdateAS400zuSellingBenutzer2 had 2 results sometimes for one entry in CSDokument and Bug 2 There were 2 entries in Table AS400Auftrag and then it switched between these two entries. So it just looked like the SET switched the two entries but it was just by chance. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're never going to see your expected results in the view. Your UPDATE statement is effectively a DELETE statement (as far as the view is concerned). Rows only appear in the view if `AD1 <> BenutzerNr`, but you're setting them to be equal.

However, the documentation for updatable views states "Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, must reference columns from only one base table." Your update statement references columns from more than one table.

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx#Updatable Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx#Updatable%20Views)

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but in my experience it's usually easier to issue the UPDATE statement against the base tables directly.

Comment: Hmm ok but I have these different tables which are interrelated. I need to compare `AD1` (`AD1` is the user number for a external worker) from `CSDokument` and `BenutzerNr` (`BenutzerNr` means user number) from `UpdateAS400zuSellingBenutzer2`. So how can I do this without a view?